# Check decimal value in DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to check if value in specific cell in DataGridView is correctly entered?

In CellFormating event I have:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
{
    string deger = (string)e.Value;
    deger = String.Format("{0:0.00}", deger);
}
```

And DefaultCellStyle is formated like:

```
dgLog.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";
```

But this still allows user to enter whatever he want. How to handle cell to allow entering only numbers with one decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event of `EditingControlShowing` In `EditingControlShowing`, check that if the current cell lies in the desired column.  Register a new event of `KeyPress` in `EditingControlShowing`(if above condition is true).Remove any `KeyPress` event added previously in `EditingControlShowing`. In `KeyPress` event, check that if `key` is not `digit` then cancel the input.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
   if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
   {
      TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
      if (tb != null)
      {
        tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
      }
    }
}

private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
       && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DataGridView CellValidating event to perform data validation in general. See [MSDN-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [MSDN-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).